# Proper way to edit existing entity in tipfy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, multiple-inheritance, tipfy

I'm using a **PersonEditHandler** class in **tipfy** to edit a Person entity. I have 
the get() and post() methods formed, but when I reference *self.person* 
(to check if the *get* method found the existing person by key), I get 
an *'object has no attribute'* error.

This is because I never initialize it in the **init** method since I'm inheriting from **RequestHandler** and **Jinja2Mixin**. However, when I override **init**, I get another error: *'TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)'*

Here is the code:

```
class PersonEditHandler(RequestHandler, Jinja2Mixin): 
    def __init__(self): 
        PersonEditHandler.__init__(self) 
        # ...or 'super(PersonEditHandler, self).__init__()' 
        self.person = None
```

Am I having trouble because of multiple inheritance? What is the best 
way to edit a retrieved record in tipfy without creating a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend foregoing the `__init__` and rather adding a class attribute:

```
class PersonEditHandler(RequestHandler, Jinja2Mixin): 
    person = None
```

This way, when you *access* a `self.person` that's never been set on a specific instance `self`, it will defer to the class and you'll get `None` as desired; when you *set* `self.person`, it will set it on the entity, as desired.

Multiple inheritance with mixins is OK, in general, but it can make for somewhat murky problems with `__new__` and `__init__`, as you've noticed (honestly I have no idea *what* class is whining about receiving three arguments here... though it would help if you showed the full traceback, finessing the problem as I just suggested is simpler;-).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I've actually already tried this. The problem is that it doesn't look like tipfy's Handlers persist items between get() and post() methods. For example, if I get an entity and store it as self.person in get, I cannot refer to self.person in post(); instead, I have to get the entity again. Someone remarked that I should use memcache to accomplish this. How would I do that?

Comment: @Wraith, it's not about tipfy -- each GAE request instantiates a brand new handler; but then setting `.person` to `None` in `__init__` would be just as useless (I see it now because you mention "persisting between get and post" -- it's not about the _methods_, if you called one from the other you'd still find everything intact!, it's about being a new **instance**!).  You could store the key/person pair in memcache (in GET) and check if it's there (in POST) as long as you know the key in POST.  But this Q is focusing on showing entirely the wrong (irrelevant) code, pls ask another!-)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer again, Alex. I've posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392990/how-do-i-store-a-fetched-entity-in-memcache-for-app-engine