# How do I store a fetched entity in memcache for App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, tipfy

Because each new request in App Engine creates a new Handler, the entity I'd like to alter and put (using POST) has to be retrieved again. This seems wasteful, since I've populated the form with the information from GET a moment earlier.

How do I store a key, fetched entity, or key/entity pair in **memcache** for App Engine?

Comment: Here is a good memcache tutorial: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching

And for tipfy users, here is a good reference for using helper methods with memcache: http://www.tipfy.org/docs/api/tipfy.ext.db.html#tipfy.ext.db.get_entity_from_protobuf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html):

```
def get_data():
    data = memcache.get("key")
    if data is not None:
        return data
    else:
        data = self.query_for_data()
        memcache.add("key", data, 60)
        return data
```

Memcache will store anything that is 'pickleable'.

You get access to memcache with the following import:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing a [simple library](https://github.com/ocanbascil/Performance-AppEngine) that enables different storage layers for datastore entities, it allows you to fetch models from datastore,memcache or local instance. You can give it a try.